# ProgressBar - работает не по клику

Tags: java, android, классы, progress-bar

Добрый день.

Имею следующую структуру класса:

```
onCreate{
Button.setOnClickListener(View v){
download_text();
}
}

public void download_text(){

        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

///код скачивания текста (вес около 2 мб)


в самом конце:        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);


}
```

ProgressBar показывается при открытии Активити, наверное, из-за того, что войд с баром вызывается по нажатию кнопки.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы прогрессБар показывался только когда пользователь нажал на кнопку и завершился при окончании скачивания.

Можно ли это сделать без AsyncTask, используя обычный public void?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, вообще не понятно ничего, идет запрос в `AsyncTask` -  показывается `ProgressBar`, как только ответ пришел, перестаем показывать его?

Comment: Судя по всему у вас изначально прогресс видимый... Сделайте его невидимым по умолчанию.

Comment: Никак. Во-первых, андроид не даст вам работать с сетью в ui-потоке, во-вторых, даже если бы и дал, на время скачивания файла у вас подвис бы интерфейс. Делайте как все, по гайдам

Answer (score 2):

Варианты работы приложения в фоновом режиме: 
 - Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
 - View.post(Runnable)
 - View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)
 - Handlers
 - AsyncTask

Однако удобнее всего и лучше всего на мой взгляд работать именно с AsyncTask.